# React useRef hook: useRef value not be used by a useState function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, use-ref

Before I asked the question I naturally did a search and found this [great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately#58877875):

I'll show my implementation in a second after I explain a little preamble.

Essentially my problem is the updater function in useState is not updating in sync, it is one behind in the data it gets.

The useState function is passed a object which contains and id, lat and lang.

```
currentCoords: [{id: 1, lat: 40.74003514370453, lng: -73.76452126968704}]
markers: [{id: 0, lat: 40.74168820148129, lng: -73.76539693565009},…]
0: {id: 0, lat: 40.74168820148129, lng: -73.76539693565009}
1: {id: 1, lat: 40.74003514370453, lng: -73.76452126968704}
```

currentCoords, should mirror the markers array. As you can see it is "setting" the second.

So I know both because setState and useState are asynchronous, you can't rely on the state being updated.

Now this is what I tried:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (userMarkers.length === 1) {
      userMarkersRef.current = userMarkers[0]; // {id: 0, lat: 40.74168820148129, lng: -73.76539693565009}
      setUserCoords(userMarkersRef.current);

      setIsRoutingVisibileFalse();
    }
    if (userMarkers.length === 2) {
      userMarkersRef.current = userMarkers[1]; // {id: 1, lat: 40.74003514370453, lng: -73.76452126968704}
      setUserCoords(userMarkersRef.current);
    }
  }, [JSON.stringify(userMarkers)]);
```

I have included in the `useEffect` dependency an array which has been stringified to kick off the hook when it (useMarkers) changes (not to worry that array never goes beyond two items!)

I figured by saving an explicit reference, and then pass it to the updater that would work, but it doesn't :(

This is the setState function, which is saving it to local storage:

```
  setUserCoords: coords => {
   setUser({
     ...user,
     currentCoords: [{ ...user.currentCoords[coords.id], ...coords }]
   });
  },
```

Comment: where does userMarkers come from?

Comment: Hi there! It is also an array on the user object being stored in local-storage.

Answer (score 1):

> Essentially my problem is the updater function in useState is not
> updating in sync, it is one behind in the data it gets.

It looks like whichever `user` is being referred to via closure inside of `setUser` is stale.

Since your next state depends on your previous state, you can use the other form of `setState` to get the most up-to-date snapshot of the previous state.

i.e -

```
setUserCoords: coords => {
   setUser((prevState) => {
     return {
       ...prevState.user,
       currentCoords: [{ ...prevState.user.currentCoords[coords.id], ...coords }]
     }
   });
  },
```

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> Both state and props received by the updater function are guaranteed
> to be up-to-date. The output of the updater is shallowly merged with
> state.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I tried your solution and I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property "currentCoords" of undefined`
`

Comment: what does the full `state` look like that `setUser` is setting?

Comment: Sorry for the delay...
`var initialState = {
  avatar: '/static/uploads/profile-avatars/placeholder.jpg',
  isRoutingVisibile: false,
  removeRoutingMachine: false,
  markers: [],
  currentMap: {},
  currentCoords: []
};
`